# How to increase stack size for thread on android via NDK?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk, google-glass, stack-size

I'm having a huge problem! I want to implement neural network for gesture recognition in my google glass app but I'm facing a StackOverFlowError. Increasing stack via new Thread(group, runnable, threadName, stackSize) DOES NOT WORK! My only solution is setting stack size using NDK! I've seen on some forums that people have managed to do that (using pthreads, pthread_attr_setstack()...) but I've never used NDK before so if anyone can tell me is this even possible (developing the app with SDK but using NDK just for setting the stack size) and if it is please direct me to some good tutorials or examples that can help me!

Comment: You have to deny the possibility that there is no bug in your code that causes infinite loops in your code first. You can do it by examining the stack trace in the exception.

Comment: There is no problem with infinite loops but with recursive method that is used for instating Neural Network that has a lot of elements that all need to be bind one with another. But thanks for commenting

Comment: In Dalvik, the native thread stack is unrelated to the Dalvik thread stack, so adjusting it through the pthreads API will accomplish nothing.  Changing it with the thread constructor does work.  The Art runtime may behave differently.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, you saved me precious time. Just one thing, setting it with thread constructor doesn't always work..